# Checking greater than or equal

Tags: php, laravel

I need to check if the displayed number is greater than or equal to 1, or not equal to 0, then we display it

I am trying to do this but I get the error

```
<span class="comments">
@if({{ $allArticleCommentsCount }} >= 1) {{ $allArticleCommentsCount }} @endif Comments
</span>
```

> syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: @if condionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the blade syntax in your if statement and you're good to go.

```
@if($allArticleCommentsCount >= 1) {{ $allArticleCommentsCount }} @endif Comments
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solution:

```
<span class="comments">
  @if( $allArticleCommentsCount >= 1) 
      {{ $allArticleCommentsCount }}
  @endif Comments
</span>
```

```
<span class="comments">
    {{ $allArticleCommentsCount >= 1 ? $allArticleCommentsCount : '' }}
</span>
```

```
@php
    if(! $allArticleCommentsCount >= 1) {
        $allArticleCommentsCount = '';
    }
@endphp
<span class="comments">
    {{ $allArticleCommentsCount }}
</span>
```

I would prefer the first solution.